# How to develop a AWS Web App that uses AWS RDS locally?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

Before moving to Amazon Web Services, I was using Google Cloud Platform to develop my aplication, CloudSQL to be specific, and GCP have something called Cloud SQL Proxy that allows me to connect to my CloudSQL instance using my computer, instead of having to deploy my code to the server and then test it. How can I make the same thing using AWS?

I have a python environment on Elastic Beanstalk, that uses Amazon RDS.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**What I did to solve was:**

1. Go to Elastic Beanstalk console
2. Chose you aplication
3. Go to Configurations
4. Click on the endpoint of your database in Databases
5. Click on the identifier of your DB Instance
6. In security group rules click in the security groups
7. Click in the inbound tab
8. Click edit
9. Change type to All Traffic and source to Anywhere
10. Save

This way you can expose the RDS connected to your Elastic Beanstalk aplication to the internet, which is not recommended as people sugested, but it is what I was looking for.

Answer (score 2):

AWS is deny be default so you cannot access an RDS instance outside of the VPC that your application is running in. With that being said... you can connect to the RDS instance via a VPN that can be stood up in EC2 that has rules open to the RDS instance. This would allow you to connect to the VPN on whatever developer machine and then access the RDS instance as if your dev box was in the VPC. This is my preferred method because it is more secure. Only those with access to the VPN have access to the RDS instance. This has worked well for me in a production sense.

The VPN provider that I use is https://aws.amazon.com/marketplace/pp/OpenVPN-Inc-OpenVPN-Access-Server/B00MI40CAE

Alternatively you could open up a hole in your VPC to the RDS instance and make it publicly available. I don't recommend this however because it will leave your RDS instance open to attack as it is publicly exposed.

Comment: I would also recommend spinning up a second RDS instance for testing that runs alongside your production RDS instance so that you can play around without touching production.

Comment: Could you please explain how to make my RDS Instance publicly available? I don't know much about networks.

Comment: Check out the section of this AWS doc titled 
"Working with a DB Instance in a VPC" 
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/USER_VPC.WorkingWithRDSInstanceinaVPC.html 

With that said I would highly recommend taking the VPN approach as publicly exposed databases can open you to attacks and the potential for a data breach.

Answer (score 1):

You can expose your AWS RDS to the internet by proper VPC setting, I did it before.

But it has some risks

So usually you can use those ways to figure it out:

1. Create a local database server and restore snapshot from your AWS RDS
2. or use VPN to connect to your private subnet which hold your RDS

Comment: Could you explain how to configure my VPC settings in the way you mentioned? I don't know much about networks.

Comment: (1) It has an option called "Publicly accessible" when you create an AWS RDS.  You need enable it. it will assign public IP address for your RDS.  (2) set your RDS into public subnet (3) set your Security group properly (open RDS port to the internet) .

Answer (score 1):

A couple people have suggested putting your RDS instance in a public subnet, and allowing access from the internet.

This is generally considered to be a bad idea, and should be the last resort.

So you have a couple of options for getting access to RDS in a private subnet.

The first option is to set up networking between your local network and your AWS VPC.  You can do this with Direct Connect, or with a point-point VPN.  But based on your question, this isn't something you feel comfortable with.

The second option is to set up a bastion server in the public subnet, and use ssh port forwarding to get local access to the RDS over the SSH tunnel.

You don't say if you on linux or Windows, but this can be accomplished on either OS.